# lenguaje c ¿Como lograr que se impriman todos los datos con gets y puts?

Tags: c

estoy realizando una estructura en c utilizando las funciones gets y puts, he logrado hacer que pidan los datos correctamente pero quiero que al final del codigo los muestre todos juntos, sin embargo no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.
mas o menos quiero que lo muestre asi:

*titulo del libro: ejemplo1*

*autor del libro: ejemplo1*

*editorial del libro: ejemplo1*

*editado en : ejemplo1*

¿Como lo podria modificar?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<string.h>

 

 

struct libro

{

char titulo[50];

char autor[30];

char editorial[30];

int anio;

}libro1;

void main()

{

  puts("Titulo del libro:\n"); 

  gets(libro1.titulo);

  puts("Autor del libro:\n");

  gets(libro1.autor);

  puts("Editorial del libro\n");

  gets(libro1.editorial);

  puts("Editado en:\n");

   gets(libro1.anio);
   
  puts("Titulo del libro:");
  puts(libro1.titulo);
 
  puts("Autor del libro: ");
  puts(libro1.autor);

  puts("Editorial del libro");
  puts(libro1.editorial);

  puts("Editado en: ");
  puts(libro1.anio);

getch();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La función [puts](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) agrega una nueva línea (`\n`) al final de la cadena a *imprimir*.

La solución es simple, debes usar la función [printf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

```c
printf("Titulo del libro:");
puts(libro1.titulo);
 
printf("Autor del libro: ");
puts(libro1.autor);

puts("Editorial del libro");
puts(libro1.editorial);

printf("Editado en: ");
puts(libro1.anio);
```

PD: No use la función [gets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/), no es seguro. Use la función [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).